# Two way databinding in AngularJs not working with async callback

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, asynchronous

So I'm trying to build an AngularJS app and am having some troubles with two way databinding between a controller and a directive when used with an async callback. I have a page controller that pulls data from a server and then uses multiple custom form directives to edit the data. Here is my setup:

```
function pageController($scope, $http) {
  // this is what the data will look like
  $scope.controllerModel = {
    obj1: {},
    obj2: {}
  }

  $http.get('get the data').then(function(data) {
    $scope.controllerModel = data; // fill in the data
    $scope.$broadcast('formDataReady'); // tell the forms the data is ready
  });
}
```

The directive:

```
module('blah').directive('customForm', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { model: '=' },
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    controller: function($scope, $attrs) {
      $scope.cleanModel = $scope.model ? _.cloneDeep($scope.model) : {};

      $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.model = _.cloneDeep($scope.cleanModel);
      };

      $scope.isClean = function() {
        return _.isEqual($scope.model, $scope.cleanModel);
      };

      // Let page controllers tell the from when the model has been loaded
      $scope.$on('formDataReady', function() {
        console.log('custom-form: resetting the clean model');
        $scope.reset();
        console.log($scope);
        console.log($scope.model);
      });

      $scope.reset();
    },
    template:
    '<div>' +
      '<form name="form" novalidate>' +
        '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
        '<div class="form-actions">' +
          '<button class="btn btn-primary" ' +
              'ng-click="save()" ' +
              'ng-disabled="form.$invalid || isClean()">' +
            'Save</button>' +
          '<button class="btn" ' +
              'ng-click="reset()" ' +
              'ng-disabled=isClean()>' +
            'Cancel</button>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</form>' +
    '</div>'
  };
});
```

And a bit of html:

```
<div ng-controller="pageController">
  <custom-form model="controllerModel.obj1">
    <!-- inputs with ng-model to edit the data -->
  </custom-form>
  <custom-form model="controllerModel.obj2">
    <!-- inputs with ng-model to edit the data -->
  </custom-form>
</div>
```

The problem is that the directive's model is not updated as a result of the async callback. **The really strange thing is** that in the event listener on the directive, those two console.log calls seem to give contradictory information:

```
console.log($scope):
  ...
  model: { object with data inside it as expected } 
  ...

console.log($scope.model):
  Object {} // empty
```

**So in the first log the scope has the model, but $scope.model is somehow empty.**

Thanks so much for any help with this. It really, really appreciated.

Comment: One thing to note is that causing the form to become invalid and then valid by changing one of the input fields updates the directive's $scope.model with all of the data (but it still doesn't have the right clean model).

Answer (score 0):

If you get your data in a `resolve` before the controller is instantiated, then the directive should read it from it just fine:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.route('myRoute', {
      url: '/myroute',
      resolve: {
         getData: function($http) {
           return $http.get('get the data').then(function(data) {
              return data;      
           }
         }
      }
    });

});

function pageController($scope, getData) {
    // getData from your $http call is now available before your controller was instantiated
    // and can be used by your directive
    $scope.controllerModel = getData;
}
```

I'm not sure why the console log is giving contradictory info though